# Why does code output ORA-00904 on code that I used a syntax verifier for?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-apex, ora-00904

So im trying to run a command in Oracel Apex to select a colum were primary key of tabel one and foreing            key of tabel 2 are the same.

```
`select name from COMP_EMPL where COMP_EMPL.employee_id = MANAGER."employee_id";`
```

When i run it the error:

```
`ORA-00904: "MANAGER"."employee_id": invalid identifier apears`
```

The tabel names are corect and the column names are corect so its not a spelling isue.
The tabels are populated and coresponding values for the two keys exist.

**Error**
[image]

**COMP_EMPL table**
[image]

**MANAGER table**
[image]

Sorry the photots are as code but it would not let me post the question otherwise (smth about bad formating)

```
I have tried removing the "" from the column names but its solved nothing i also tried renaming the column but nothing changed same error with diferent name also the same error apears werever i use MANAGER."employee_id"  so its not an isue with that specific comand.
```

Comment: the table manager is nit know to the query, so you need to join all tables, when you need their columns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, code you posted is invalid. It is a **join** you need; you can't  reference the `MANAGER` table in `WHERE` clause *just because*. Correct syntax is

```
select c."name"
from comp_empl c join manager m on m.employee_id = c."employee_id"
```

For example, with some sample data:

```
SQL> with
  2  comp_empl ("employee_id", "name") as
  3    (select 1, 'Little' from dual),
  4  manager ("manager_id", employee_id) as
  5    (select 100, 1 from dual)
```

Query you'd use:

```
  6  select c."name"
  7  from comp_empl c join manager m on m.employee_id = c."employee_id"
  8  /

name
------
Little

SQL>
```

Note double quotes I used for identifiers. They are necessary because you chose to create tables using double quotes. It means that you have to enclose them into double quotes EVERY TIME you reference them. If you used mixed letter case, you'd have to match letter case as well.

Shortly: it is a bad idea to use double quotes when working with Oracle. By default, Oracle stores names (tables, procedures, columns, ...) in uppercase, but lets you reference them using any letter case you want **unless** you used double quotes.

If you look at e.g. `MANAGER` table, you'll see that `manager_id` is created in lower case (so you have to enclose it into double quotes and write lower case), while `EMPLOYEE_ID` is written in upper case (so you can reference it using upper case, or enclose them into double quotes but also with upper case).

On the other hand, **all** columns in `COMP_EMPL` table were created in lower case (which means with double quotes).

---

If I were you, I'd drop both tables and create new ones as e.g.

```
create table manager
  (manager_id    number,
   employee_id   number
  );
```

Then you can use all this:

```
select * from MAnaGer where EMPLOYEE_id = 1
or
select EMPLOYEe_Id from manager where MANAGER_ID = 100
or ...
```

Using sample data from beginning of this post:

```
SQL> with
  2  comp_empl (employee_ID, NAme) as
  3    (select 1, 'Little' from dual),
  4  manager (MANAGER_id, EmPlOyEe_ID) as
  5    (select 100, 1 from dual)
  6  select c.name
  7  from comp_empl c join manager m on m.employee_id = c.employee_id;

NAME
------
Little

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

The error appears because there is no "MANAGER" table in the FROM clause. If you reference a table in the where clause, it needs to exist in the FROM clause. In your case a simple join would do, there where clause is not needed. This statement does the same as what you're trying to achieve:

```
select name 
  from COMP_EMPL C
       JOIN MANAGER M ON C.employee_id = M.employee_id
```

Comment: Im not sure about what u said with FROM clause is correct or wrong cuz a syntax verifier said my code is correct and I remember using similar commands as the one in the original post in other SQL apps and them working but the code u provided gives the same error only it switches from the MANAGER table to the COMP_EMPL  _____________

ORA-00904: "C"."EMPLOYEE_ID": invalid identifier

Comment: @bogdanmaxim your syntax verifier is wrong. Your FROM clause only refers to `COMP_EMPL`, so how is MANAGER supposed to be resolved?